# WIC Read GIF file

Tags: c++, winapi, wic

I'm trying to load all frames in a GIF with Windows Imaging Component. On some GIF files I have an issue. For example, with the attached GIF image (error handling removed, all calls succeed):

```
            // Load all frames
            CComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> pDecoder = NULL;
            wbfact->CreateDecoderFromFilename(
                        file.c_str(),
                        NULL, GENERIC_READ,
                        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnLoad,
                        &pDecoder
                    );
            UINT FrameCount = 0;
            pDecoder->GetFrameCount(&FrameCount); // 66 in this GIF

            for (int i = 0; i < FrameCount; i++)
            {
                    CComPtr<IWICBitmapFrameDecode> s2 = NULL;
                    pDecoder->GetFrame(i, &s2);
                    CComPtr<IWICFormatConverter> pConverter2 = NULL;
                    wbfact->CreateFormatConverter(&pConverter2);
                    pConverter2->Initialize(
                                s2,
                                GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA,
                                WICBitmapDitherTypeNone,
                                NULL,
                                0.f,
                                WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut
                            );


            }
```

Most times this works. However in this attached gif some frames are not shown (e.g. frame 2) and some frames are only shown with their edges, e.g. frame 26.
[image]

[image]

It looks like as if some GIFs contain a progressive encoding that is not read by WIC.
Many GIFS display correctly. Also, Windows players display the gifs correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

Best,

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wic/wicanimatedgif

Comment: Not sure you're doing anything wrong, this is what I got too https://i.imgur.com/K1bMNHI.png and metadata https://pastebin.com/raw/U02cBVNF (using this https://github.com/smourier/WicNet). Note 2, 18, 35 and 51 are just 1x1 size and are just a transparent pixel. 25 and 59 are exact same position and contains also lot of transparent information, so when animated, the visual result is correct.

Comment: From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF  *"Strategies for minimizing file size [...] and minimizing the number of pixels covered in successive frames (so that only the pixels that change from one frame to the next are included in the latter frame)."*